# Must a business/non-profit share a single login for eBay account?

Tags: account-management, ebay

I am creating a business (non-profit) eBay account for fundraising.  I need to authorize other volunteers to create and manage listings.  Must we all share a single password for logging in, or is there a way to grant permissions to other logins?  It is much better from a security standpoint for each worker to have their own credentials and be granted privileges as appropriate to their role.

*Update:*  I also created a MissionFish account through which the fees for successful sales are refunded and the sale is donated to the nonprofit.  Although the organization won't earn reputation on an official eBay account, MissionFish allows designating other eBay accounts as authorized sellers.  That,  at least, resolves the password sharing situation.

Comment: Have you asked eBay?

Comment: I have not.  I did a search, but only found "Third-party Authorizations" which is not related to what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Some kind of integration with an eCommerce solution, which supports multiple user accounts would definitely help with the listing and user account and password problem. However as I understand an integration like this would only really provide product synchronization to and from eBay.

Depending on the product range and the expected messaging required trough eBay might require an email-based ticket system. However, as eBay is built to "record" all conversation thorough their own messaging system a separate system might be confusing to use for many including both users and potential agents.

Answer (score 0):

The app ChannelReply would solve the issue with managing eBay buyer messages and returns/refunds, for example, but will most likely not be able to help with setting up listings.

If MissionFish allows designated other eBay accounts, that's great!